# MDriven ECO_ID duplicates

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, concurrency, mdriven

We appear to have a problem with MDriven generating the same ECO_ID for multiple objects. For the most part it seems to happen in conjunction with unexpected process shutdowns and/or server shutdowns, but it does also happen during normal activity.

Our system consists of one ASP.NET application and one WinForms application. The ASP.NET app is setup in IIS to use a single worker process. We have a mixture of WebForms and MVC, including ApiControllers. We're using a rather old version of the ECO packages: 7.0.0.10021. We're on VS 2017, target framework is 4.7.1.

We have it configured to use 64 bit integers for object id:s. Database is Firebird. SQL configuration is set to use ReadCommitted transaction isolation.

As far as I can tell we have configured `EcoSpaceStrategyHandler` with `EcoSpaceStrategyHandler.SessionStateMode.Never`, which should mean that EcoSpaces are not reused at all, right? (Why would I even use `EcoSpaceStrategyHandler` in this case, instead of just creating EcoSpace normally with the `new` keyword?)

We have created `MasterController : Controller` and `MasterApiController : ApiController` classes that we use for all our controllers. These have a `EcoSpace` property that simply does this:

```
if (ecoSpace == null)
{
    if (ecoSpaceStrategyHandler == null)
        ecoSpaceStrategyHandler = new EcoSpaceStrategyHandler(
            EcoSpaceStrategyHandler.SessionStateMode.Never,
            typeof(DiamondsEcoSpace),
            null,
            false
        );
    ecoSpace = (DiamondsEcoSpace)ecoSpaceStrategyHandler.GetEcoSpace();
}
return ecoSpace;
```

I.e. if no strategy handler has been created, create one specifying no pooling and no session state persisting of eco spaces. Then, if no ecospace has been fetched, fetch one from the strategy handler. Return the ecospace. Is this an acceptable approach? Why would it be better than simply doing this:

```
if (ecoSpace = null)
    ecoSpace = new DiamondsEcoSpace();
return ecoSpace;
```

In aspx we have a master page that has an `EcoSpaceManager`. It has been configured to use a pool but `SessionStateMode` is `Never`. It has `EnableViewState` set to `true`. Is this acceptable? Does it mean that EcoSpaces will be pooled but inactivated between round trips?

It is possible that we receive multiple incoming API calls in tight succession, so that one API call hasn't been completed before the next one comes in. I assume that this means that multiple instances of `MasterApiController` can execute simultaneously but in separate threads. There may of course also be `MasterController` instances executing MVC requests and also the WinForms app may be running some batch job or other.

But as far as I understand id reservation is made at the beginning of any `UpdateDatabase` call, in this way:

```
update "ECO_ID" set "BOLD_ID" = "BOLD_ID" + :N;
select "BOLD_ID" from "ECO_ID";
```

If the returned value is K, this will reserve N new id:s ranging from K - N to K - 1. Using ReadCommitted transactions everywhere should ensure that the update locks the id data row, forcing any concurrent save operations to wait, then fetches the update result without interference from other transactions, then commits. At that point any other pending save operation can proceed with its own id reservation. I fail to see how this could result in the same ID being used for multiple objects.

I should note that it does seem like it sometimes produces id duplicates within one single UpdateDatabase, i.e. when saving a set of new related objects, some of them end up with the same id. I haven't really confirmed this though.

Any ideas what might be going on here? What should I look for?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is most likely that you use ReadCommitted isolation.
This allows for 2 systems to simultaneously start a transaction, read the current value, increase the batch, and then save after each other.

You must use Serializable isolation for key generation; ie only read things not currently in a write operation.

MDriven use 2 settings for isolation level UpdateIsolationLevel and FetchIsolationLevel.

Set your UpdateIsolationLevel to Serializable

Comment: OK, I will try and let it run for a while to see if it makes a difference. But if the key fetcher would start by doing an update and then a select, as I see in the SQL log from the Firebird provider, then no other transaction can do an update until the first one commits. That should prevent duplicates. From your reply it would seem that the key fetcher sometimes/always starts with a select and then an update. Is that really the case?

Comment: The important thing is if the select and update is in the same serializable transaction or not. Doing a relative update (update X set y=y+10) is not supported in all db's I think - and even if it was the implementation in the db might be "select + update" and then the issue with isolation level would still apply.

Comment: Understood. In that case I would actually expect the framework to enforce serializable for key fetch and doing that in a dedicated short-lived transaction that does nothing else. If I set the entire system to serializable I fear I will get a severe performance hit and possibly also deadlocks, considering readers will block writers in that isolation level, and as far as I understand those locks apply to entire tables, not just specific rows (but I may be mistaken about that detail). In some batch runs I save tens of thousands of objects in a single `UpdateDatabase.`..

Comment: I should add that unless I'm totally off the mark here, MDriven actually does a relative update then a select during `UpdateDabase`, as far as I've seen in SQL logs from the Firebird ADO provider. I do know that under ReadCommitted transaction this should work in Firebird. It would NOT work if it was done as select and then update, because in that situation a concurrent transaction may read the same value beween the first transaction's select and update operations. This is a "no no"...

Can I hook in my own ID reservation mechanism into MDriven?

Comment: Anyway you try will have the same problem of someone reading the last commited value and acting on it before you commit - in this case serialization is the only alternative. You may create your own key definition if needed

Comment: The question is why anyone would read "next available id" without first reserving N id:s using an update, which would always have to wait until any concurrent such operation completes, thus ensuring unique id:s. A key reservation system that reads without preceding update would i.m.h.o. be a buggy key reservation system. Are you saying MDriven is buggy?